# There is a unit sequence weakly converging to every element of unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

> > Suppose the Hilbert space $H$ has a countable (I assume Hilbert?) basis.  Let $x \in H$ be such that $\lvert x \rvert \leq 1$.  Show that there exists a sequence $\{u_{n}\}$ in $H$ with $\lvert u_{n} \rvert = 1$ for all $n$ such that $\{u_{n}\}$ converges weakly to $x$.

By hypothesis, for the Hilbert basis $\{v_{n}\}$,
$$x = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{n}v_{n}.$$
I think my issue is with the requirement that $u_{n}$ have unit norm.  The only unit sequence I could come up with was $\lvert s_{m}\rvert^{-1}s_{m}$, where
$$s_{m} = \sum_{n = 1}^{m} a_{n}v_{n},$$
which apparently converges to $\lvert x \rvert^{-1} x$.  This seems to work if $\lvert x \rvert$ is on the unit sphere, but I'm not sure what to do otherwise.  Also, I've noticed that I haven't really used the fact that the sequence should converge weakly.

Comment: If $z_n$ converges weakly to $0$, then $x + \lambda_n\cdot z_n$ converges weakly to $x$ for all bounded sequences $(\lambda_n)$.

Comment: $\lambda_n$ so that $\lvert x+\lambda_n v_n\rvert = 1$ suffices and $\lambda_n$ bounded by 2?

Comment: Indeed, that suffices. You can even take $\lvert\lambda_n\rvert \leqslant 1$, if you take $\lambda_n$ in the same direction as $\langle x,v_n\rangle$.